# Hyperref issues

Tags: hyperref, packages, package-options

I want to use hyperref in my work "report", and (option clash for package color) is the error message I am receiving with my report document class. This is a part of my preamble with error message that "option clash for package color"

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linktoc=all, linkcolor=red, citecolor=green]{hyperref, color}
\usepackage{apacite}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linktoc=all, linkcolor=red, citecolor=green]{hyperref, color} ` is wrong as none of those options apply to the`color` package. It is probably enough to simply delete `,color`. But in general if you want help with an error please provide a small complete document that generates the error.

Comment: Thank you David, it just worked out when I deleted the option ,color. Thanks from Nigeria

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linktoc=all, linkcolor=red, citecolor=green]{hyperref, color}
```

is wrong as none of those options apply to the color package. It is probably enough to simply delete `, color`